# Iterating through polymer content insertion points

Tags: polymer, web-component

What I'd like is for the following html:

```
<father name = "John">
  <son name = "Bob">likes lollipops</son>
  <son name = "David">likes computers</son>
</father>
```

to generate:

```
John has two sons, Bob and David:

Bob: likes lollipops
David: likes computers
```

Now, assume I've correctly written the "son" polymer tag, and it renders a block div with "Bob: likes lolipops" as the contents. this I can get working easily, so that I have something like:

```
John

Bob: likes lolipops
David: likes computers
```

However, to get that top line, I'm really not sure what the correct approach is, basically I'd like something like this:

```
<polymer-element name = "father" attributes = "name">
    <template>
        <style>...
        </style>
        <div layout vertical>
            {{name}} has ???{count}??? sons, ???{{ iterate son nodes, print out name attribute for each }}???<br/>
            <!-- I dont know how ot access JS here, so not sure how to turn all child nodes into a children array -->
            <content select = "son"></content>
        </div> 
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({});
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a few ways of doing this, but here's one approach. (Full version on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/juhuya/edit)).

```
<polymer-element name="son-element" attributes="name" noscript>
  <template>
    <p>{{name}}: <content></content></p>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="father-element" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <p>{{name}} has {{count}} sons, {{sons}}:</p>
    <p><content id="content"></content></p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      count: 0,
      sons: '',
      domReady: function() {
        var names = [].map.call(this.children, function(sonElement) {
          return sonElement.name;
        });
        this.count = names.length;
        this.sons = names.join(' and ');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<father-element name="John">
  <son-element name="Bob">likes lollipops</son-element>
  <son-element name="David">likes computers</son-element>
</father-element>
```

The key piece is hooking into the `domReady` [lifecycle method](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods) of `<father-element>`, and inspecting its, erm, `children`. Since we know they'll all be `<son-element>`s, we just blindly look for their name attributes and map them to an array, but if you wanted you could take some steps to only query for the `<son-element>`s.

(Oh, and Polymer elements all need to have a `-` in their names, so you'd need to go with `<father-element>` (or the like) instead of `<father>`.)

Comment: ProTip: This is a fine solution, but examining `this.children` has limited utility for two reasons: (1) if the elements are projected (by `<content>`) they will not be in `children` and (2) children may come and go. Whenever possible, explicitly handshake the relationships. For example, have `<son-element>` fire a `son-added` event when `attached()` and a `son-removed` event when `detached()`. The `father-element` can listen for these events and manage the relationships directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it is based on Jeff Posnick's solution but with Scott Miles suggestion to listen for add- remove- events.

```
<polymer-element name="baby-element" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <p>{{name}}: <content></content> <input type="button" value="Kill Baby" on-click="{{killBaby}}"/></p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer("baby-element", {
      attached: function(){
        this.fire('baby-added');
      },
      killBaby: function(){
        this.fire('baby-removed');
  //    this.remove();
      },
      detached: function() {
        this.fire('baby-removed');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="parent-element" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <p>{{name}} has {{count}} babys, {{babys}}:</p>
    <p><content id="content"></content></p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      count: 0,
      babys: '',
      domReady: function() {
        this.recalcBabys();
        this.addEventListener('baby-added', this.babyAdded);
        this.addEventListener('baby-removed', this.babyRemoved);
      },
      babyRemoved: function(e) {
        e.target.remove();
        this.recalcBabys();
      },
      babyAdded: function(e) {
        this.recalcBabys();
      },
      recalcBabys: function(){
        var names = [].map.call(this.children, function(babyElement) {
          return babyElement.name;
        });
        this.count = names.length;
        this.babys = names.join(' and ');
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>

<h1>It's aparent baby thing:</h1>
<input type=button value="make baby" id="makeBaby"></input>
<input type=input placeholder="baby name" id="babyName"></input>
<input type=input placeholder="baby info" id="babyInfo"></input>

<parent-element id="parent" name="Slim Sim">
  <baby-element name="Curie">has X</baby-element>
  <baby-element name="Korbut">volts like no other!</baby-element>
  <baby-element name="Pavlov">has dogs!</baby-element>
  <baby-element name="Schrodinger">... maybe has a cat?</baby-element>
</parent-element>


<script>
  document.getElementById('makeBaby').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var name = document.getElementById('babyName');
    var info = document.getElementById('babyInfo');
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    var baby = document.createElement("baby-element");
    var inner = document.createTextNode(info.value);
    baby.appendChild(inner);
    baby.setAttribute("name",name.value);
    parent.appendChild(baby);
  });
</script>
```

I did not manage to get the parent-element to recalculateBabys if the baby is removed from outside, with for instance `document.getElementsByTagName('baby-element')[0].remove()`.

I would have liked to (on the baby-element) only have the attached and detached methods fire the baby-added and baby-removed events, and the killBaby-funktion to only do 'this.remove()'.
But I could never get the Parent to hear all those events...

Please feel free to scrutinize this code and tell me any errors, I am kind of new to Polymer, but I still hop I can contribute!